# Python: If..else.. condition on printing lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code to search 13th column to be matched if field-2 of the line is "IT", and 14th column to be matched if field-2 of the line is "FW". (from the data that has in "l".. this will split into lines, where every line starts with "TEC")

```
"IT"[13thCOL] start numbers to be matched from FILTER variables.
"FW"[14thCOL] start numbers to be matched from FILTER variables.
```

I tried to put logic in IF..ELSE condition, but somehow my if condition is not working well.

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

l =  ['TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311497,20180509042152355,20180509042152355,0,480,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,7ee0dd6bb34472945b18c959049f514f@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+442086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.13:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311498,20180509042152828,20180509042152828,0,480,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,5f29e2b4ef5a19c6a489aa53f01c000c@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+442086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.13:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311499,20180509042153373,20180509042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+444441499737979,sip:+441499737979,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441499737979@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,1001501', 'TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311500,20180509042358780,20180509042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441498738722,sip:+441498738722,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441498738722@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+441498738722,sip:+441498738722@example.com,1000201']
FILTER = ['sip:+420', 'sip:+34', 'sip:+44149']
result = []
for row in l:
    r = row.split(',')
    if r[1] == 'IT':
       result.append([i for i in l if any(x in i.split(',')[12] for x in FILTER)])
    elif r[1] == 'FW':
       result.append([i for i in l if any(x in i.split(',')[13] for x in FILTER)])
    else:
       pass
print("result is")
next = reduce(operator.concat, result)
print('\n'.join(next))
```

getting output as

```
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501
TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311499,20180509042153373,20180509042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+444441499737979,sip:+441499737979,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441499737979@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,1001501
TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311500,20180509042358780,20180509042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441498738722,sip:+441498738722,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441498738722@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+441498738722,sip:+441498738722@example.com,1000201
TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311499,20180509042153373,20180509042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+444441499737979,sip:+441499737979,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441499737979@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,1001501
TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311500,20180509042358780,20180509042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441498738722,sip:+441498738722,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441498738722@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+441498738722,sip:+441498738722@example.com,1000201
```

required output:

```
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501
TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311499,20180509042153373,20180509042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+444441499737979,sip:+441499737979,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441499737979@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUST,C15_GR01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,1001501
TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311500,20180509042358780,20180509042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441498738722,sip:+441498738722,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441498738722@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+441498738722,sip:+441498738722@example.com,1000201
```

from IF..ELSE condition I want to print all matched lines into single variable. I am not sure why lines matched with "IT" are printing 2 times..

Comment: Below, you have my answer without your logic (code inside `if .. elif ...` bloc.). It will be good to provide a desired result for `result`when the field is "IT" and when it is "FW"...

Comment: hi thanks for help. after making changes as per below, I am now able to execute without indexError, but IF..ELSE condition had problem, that I didn't apply append. My requirement is to see al lines in same "output" variable, So could you please help how can I use append to "output" variable.

Comment: It is good to "upvote" a code that help you. Update your post, and provide us an example of the desired output..

Comment: Check your example `l`. For this example, I think, it is not 5 lines but **3** lines that matched...

Comment: In your `required output:`, the first three lines are repeated. So, normally, the `required output` should contains three lines instead of five... Check it !!

Comment: thanks codrelphi.. it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = ['TEC,FW,AS.blaram.111,311496,20181009042152033,20181009042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@20.116.21.9,Cisco-CUCM20.5,sip:+ACE8777447585984834,sip:+220037585984834,sip:+42086081330@man.blaram.com,sip:+8777447585984834@20.116.21.51:5060,sip:+221344903000@20.120.70.132:5060,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,CUST56,C15_GR01,pstn,+221491668070,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,CUST56,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+227585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,FW,AS.blaram.111,311497,20181009042152355,20181009042152355,0,480,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,7ee0dd6bb34472945b18c959049f514f@20.116.21.9,NotPresent,sip:+ACE8777447585984834,sip:+220037585984834,sip:+222086081330@man.blaram.com,sip:+8777447585984834@man.blaram.com:5060,sip:+221344903000@20.116.21.13:5060,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,CUST56,C15_GR01,pstn,+221491668070,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,CUST56,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+227585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,FW,AS.blaram.111,311498,20181009042152828,20181009042152828,0,480,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,5f29e2b4ef5a19c6a489aa53f01c000c@20.116.21.9,NotPresent,sip:+ACE8777447585984834,sip:+220037585984834,sip:+222086081330@man.blaram.com,sip:+8777447585984834@man.blaram.com:5060,sip:+221344903000@20.116.21.13:5060,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,CUST56,C15_GR01,pstn,+221491668070,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,CUST56,C15_GR01,mobile,447585984834000,+227585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,IT,AS.blaram.111,311499,20181009042153373,20181009042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@20.116.21.9,NotPresent,sip:+224441491668070,sip:+221491668070,sip:+222086081330@1.1.9.1,sip:+224441491668070@man.blaram.com:5060,sip:+221344903000@20.116.21.17:5080,CUST56,C15_GR01,pstn,+221491668070,sip:+221491668070@man.blaram.com,1001501', 'TEC,IT,AS.blaram.111,311500,20181009042358780,20181009042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@20.116.21.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441491603331,sip:+221491603331,sip:+222086081330@1.1.9.1,sip:+224441491603331@man.blaram.com:5060,sip:+221344903000@20.116.21.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+221491603331,sip:+221491603331@man.blaram.com,1000201']

# I remove this line: te = '\n'.join(l)
FILTER = ['sip:+220', 'sip:+494', 'sip:+119']

for row in l:

    # for each row, you split by ','
    r = row.split(',') # so, r = ['TEC', 'IT', ...]

    # r[1] will always be 'IT' or 'FW' 
    if r[1] == 'IT':

        # add your logic here

    elif r[1] == 'FW':
        # add your logic here

print('\n'.join(result))
```

> **Update**

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

l =  ['TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311497,20180509042152355,20180509042152355,0,480,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,7ee0dd6bb34472945b18c959049f514f@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+442086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.13:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311498,20180509042152828,20180509042152828,0,480,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,5f29e2b4ef5a19c6a489aa53f01c000c@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+442086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.13:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501', 'TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311499,20180509042153373,20180509042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+444441499737979,sip:+441499737979,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441499737979@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,1001501', 'TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311500,20180509042358780,20180509042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441498738722,sip:+441498738722,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441498738722@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+441498738722,sip:+441498738722@example.com,1000201']
FILTER = ['sip:+420', 'sip:+34', 'sip:+44149']
result = []

for row in l:
    r = row.split(',')
    if r[1] == 'IT':
        if (r[12][:8] in FILTER) or (r[12][:7] in FILTER) or (r[12][:10] in FILTER):
            result.append(row)

    if r[1] == 'FW':
        if (r[13][:8] in FILTER) or (r[13][:7] in FILTER) or (r[13][:10] in FILTER):
            result.append(row)

for row in result:
    print(row)
    print() # jump  line between the output result
```

> **Output**

```
TEC,FW,AS.example.111,311496,20180509042152033,20180509042152033,0,480,j8vg3046nhcs2p47ehci3ng6gpgal9hah9dqi1h9hhfaj100,3507b59a19602f0c96792e180d2469d1@10.105.86.9,Cisco-CUCM10.5,sip:+PLT8777447585984834,sip:+440093779379739,sip:+42086081330@example.com,sip:+8777447585984834@10.105.86.51:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.110.70.132:5060,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,CUST,M79_PL01,mobile,447585984834000,+447585984834,onnet,1001501,1001501

TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311499,20180509042153373,20180509042202478,9105,normal,afc81a7e0aefe660dabb2963acf280,bc4213fa64c67cbdc8e80c5a437a7677@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+444441499737979,sip:+441499737979,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441499737979@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUST,M79_PL01,pstn,+441499737979,sip:+441499737979@example.com,1001501

TEC,IT,AS.example.111,311500,20180509042358780,20180509042414784,16004,normal,8deba7200aefe860dabb2b5049eb70,279e60f3eb07aa44c55b8a4b804667bf@10.105.86.9,NotPresent,sip:+744441498738722,sip:+441498738722,sip:+442086081330@172.16.90.1,sip:+444441498738722@example.com:5060,sip:+441344903000@10.105.86.17:5080,CUSTOMER02,GROUP01 - CLUSTER1,pstn,+441498738722,sip:+441498738722@example.com,1000201
```

> **UPDATE: Explanations**

When the 2nd column is `IT`, you are interested by the 13th column. So `r[12]` gives something like: `sip:+441498738722`.
When the 2nd column is `FW`, you are interested by the 14th column. So, `r[13]` gives something like: `sip:+442086081330@example.com`.

Your filter is: `FILTER = ['sip:+420', 'sip:+34', 'sip:+44149']`. It contains 3 items. The length of the 1st item is **8**.
The length of the 2nd item is **7** and the length of the last item is **10**.

So to know if the `r[12]` (`sip:+441498738722`) or `r[13]` (`sip:+442086081330@example.com`) elements are in the `FILTER`,
you have to take the first 8, 7 and 10 characters and test **if one of them (at least)** is in the `FILTER`.

```
if (r[12][:8] in FILTER) or (r[12][:7] in FILTER) or (r[12][:10] in FILTER):
    # code
```

**For example:** `r[12]` is `sip:+441498738722`. So the first 8 characters are `r[12][:8]` which is `sip:+441`. The first 7
characters are `r[12][:7]` which is `sip:+44`. The first 10 characters are `r[12][:10]` which is `sip:+44149`. Now, you can
see that for this `r[12]` (`sip:+441498738722`), only `r[12][:10]` (`sip:+44149`) is in the `FILTER` variable. So, you can
add this `row` to the `result` list.

It is the same logic, when the 2nd column of the `row` is `FW`.

Comment: Hello codrelphi, I have updated my question, and given required output.. my logic works fine individually, but in IF..ELSE condtion I am not sure why it is printing lines multiple times.. Please help

Comment: could you please help me to understand this line if (r[12][:8] in FILTER) or (r[12][:7] in FILTER) or (r[12][:10] in FILTER):

Comment: you can simplify the filter check if-statement to maintain the original syntax. see my answer for an example. @Maria

Comment: In your the first code , when you do `result.append([i for i in l if any(x in i.split(',')[13] for x in FILTER)])`, you add another list in the `result` list. After, it can be difficult to you to achieve your goal....

Comment: Now, if you don't understand the WHY of this syntax: `r[12][:8] in FILTER or r[12][:7] in FILTER or r[12][:10] in FILTER`, I can explain.

Comment: @coderelphi.. Yes,, Could you please tell me about syntax --  r[12][:8] in FILTER or r[12][:7] in FILTER or r[12][:10] in FILTER

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

since you changed your original question and code (which you shouldn't do) here is a fix to your new question

change

```py
result.append([i for i in l if any(x in i.split(',')[12] for x in FILTER)])
```

to

```py
if any(x in r[12] for x in FILTER):
    result.append(row)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

it looks like `te` is a string which means when you loop

```py
for row in te
```

you're looping over each character (i.e. `row` is a single character) which doesn't have index 1 (a second element)

I think to accomplish what you want you should remove this line

```py
te = '\n'.join(l)
```

which combines the list into a single string. and instead use this

```py
te = [x.split(',') for x in l]
```

which uses list comprehension to split each row of `l` into a list which you can index with `row[1]`